# Flexdatalist, multiple data sources for quicker searches

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, flexdatalist

I'm using this plugin:
http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist

To render "autocomplete results" in a search input. It works great.

```
$oginput.flexdatalist({
    minLength: 2,
    valueProperty: '*',
    searchContain: true,
    normalizeString: function (string) {
        return string.toLowerCase();
    },
    visibleProperties: ["title", "par_title", "type", "url"],
    searchIn: 'title',
    data: siteurl + '/search-data'
});
```

however, the data loaded from the URL `siteurl + '/search-data'` is quite large (1000s of rows) and there is a delay of several seconds between typing and the results rendering.

What I would like to do is load a much smaller JSON array with popular searches directly to the page (no ajax request necessary)... to search this array initially, and if no results are found in the smaller array, then make the ajax request to the full array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!